# How to get text by id from array? React

Tags: javascript

```
CurrentUserAnswerVariants:

    {id: "4468cdc8-220d-4634-9d68-6c9920e0cb48", text: "Question 1", 
     minAnswersQuantity: 1, maxAnswersQuantity: 1, canComment: false,
     canComment: false, currentUserAnswerVariants: ["ecc0b93c-8e3b-4661-8f2e-f5382a74d79b"], id: "4468cdc8-220d-4634-9d68-6c9920e0cb48" }
const answers = [];

        this.setState({questionGroups}, () => {

            this.state.questionGroups.map((questionGroup) => {
                questionGroup.questions.map((question) => {
                    // questionGroup.questions.variants.map((variant) => {
                    const currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantIds = question.currentUserAnswerVariants.filter(variant => ["canComment"].indexOf(variant) === -1);
                    const currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantText = question.currentUserAnswerVariants.filter(variant => currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantIds === variant.id).text;
                    const answer = {
                        questionId: question.id
                    };

                    if (!isNull(question.currentUserAnswerComment)) {
                        answer["comment"] = question.currentUserAnswerComment;
                    }

                    if (currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantIds.length) {
                        answer["variantIds"] = currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantIds;
                    }
                    if (currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantText) {
                        answer["variantText"] = currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantText;
                    }

                    answers.push(answer);


                    console.log(questionGroup.questions.variants);
                    // });

                });
            });

        });
    };
```

How to get by currentUserAnswerVariants value  text from variants array by id?
[My array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r46OO.png) Please can u see this image where is my array and when i check some variant i have new array [Answer array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8bvG.png)

Comment: `.filter(variant => variant.id === idLookingFor)[0].text;`

Comment: text is undefinded

Comment: Don't use filter on currentUserAnswerVariants array but the variants array instead, then  `question.Variants.filter(variant => currentUserAnswerVariants === variant.id)[0].text` where `currentUserAnswerVariants` is the id or variant id in currentUserAnswerVariants array

Comment: Can u check my array when i use ur code i have a text is undef

Answer (score 0):

```
function idEquals(idToCompare, question) {
    return question.id.indexOf(idToCompare) === 0;
}

currentUserAnswerVariantsVariantIds = question.filter(idEquals.bind(this, currentUserAnswerVariants));
```

Does this work?
It's something along these lines, and you may edit the following code accordingly.

Comment: what happens? can you print the content of the question variable?

Comment: Can u write function like react use it and i didnt see text taking in ur code

Answer (score 0):

1. $var = $('#id').val();
2. $var['text'];
   -> only if you need single id text

-> or use foreach on id and push the each result into one blank array and print array