# How to send e.target second value?

Tags: reactjs

I have input (onChangeCheckbox) with e.target and can't take second value

```
function Variant({variant: {id, text}, ...rest}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <CheckBox label={text} value={id} {...rest} />
        </div>
    );
}

Variant.propTypes = {
    variant: PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.string,
        text: PropTypes.string
    }).isRequired
};
//next file code father
    onChangeCheckbox = e => {
            const {value, label} = e.target;
            const {question: {currentUserAnswerVariants, currentUserAnswerComment, maxAnswersQuantity}, updateQuestion, index} = this.props;
            const answerIndex = currentUserAnswerVariants.indexOf(value);

            console.log(e.target.value);

            if (answerIndex === -1) {
                currentUserAnswerVariants.push(value);
            }

            updateQuestion(index, {
                currentUserAnswerVariants,
                currentUserAnswerComment: currentUserAnswerVariants.indexOf("canComment") === -1 ? null : currentUserAnswerComment
            });
        };
```

Label is undefinded but i have this in array [How to get text by id from array? React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215680/how-to-get-text-by-id-from-array-react)

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce an issue?

Comment: can you console log e.target.value.value and e.target.label.value  and also please show how you are calling onCheckCheckBox function